# dynamic script loading - is it safe?

Tags: javascript, loading

```
function LoadFoo(selected_foo) {
var foobar = selected_foo.bar;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var nextfoo = document.createElement('script');
nextfoo.type= 'text/javascript';
nextfoo.src="foobaz.php?form=foo" + ... + "&foobar=" + foobar; // a php script which reads from MYSQL and generates script that updates selectboxes of the document
head.appendChild(nextfoo) }
```

tested on Chrome Version 23.0.1271.26, FF 16, IE 9 and no problem so far. But I'm kinda worried, since I never have worked on JS before, and it is not tested on IE6~8. also, since more `nextfoo` object will be created on each execution, wouldn't it be problematic? I tried appeding `head.removeChild(nextfoo);` , and dropped it because it made `nextfoo` not working on IE9.

Comment: Why is the JS source pointing to a PHP file?

Comment: because previous author of LoadFoo() made it that way. I can't change that part of the script. anyway by reading some pages on dynamic script loading, some people claim that .src attribute must be manipulated after appendChild() part, not before the appendChild() like what I wrote, in order to work in IE7. Is it correct?

Comment: It should work either way, unless there's something funky about IE7 that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code creates new script tags, its less than ideal but it wont really cause any problems (other than possibly having hundreds of script tags added to your page. Changing it to use xmlhttp or something similar would be better. Reading your comment I guess your kinda stuck with what you have though?

If your just having problems with the .src attribute you could try setting it using setAttribute.

```
function LoadFoo(selected_foo) {
var foobar = selected_foo.bar;
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var nextfoo = document.createElement('script');
nextfoo.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
nextfoo.setAttribute("src", "foobaz.php?form=foo" + ... + "&foobar=" + foobar);
head.appendChild(nextfoo) }
```

I'm not sure where you'r going with the removeChild() bit, if your trying to remove the one you've just loaded after its complete you can't add it to this function. (it might remove the element before its loaded)

You can remove old foo's (by adding an ID or something to differentiate each script tag) but if your loading lots of them quickly you could face the same problem of removing one that is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just leave them and when I find new problems I'll try using setAttribute. I expect at average 10~20 new sciprt tags will be added to that page and I think modern web browsers may have no problem handling it.